# Apache works in Ubuntu 18.04 but gets an error reading error.php

Tags: 18.04, apache2, php

Apache works in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but gets an error reading error.php or phpinfo.php page. The server-status page works so apache is working but can't read php pages. I tried to edit apache2.conf but didn't work. Can you help please? Thanks

Comment: Did you install the Apache PHP module? What is your apache version!

Comment: Probably not George,  I just did this one    $ sudo apt-get install apache2. and this one I think, apt-get install php. When I go  php -v It shows that php7.2 is installed. Maybe its best to start again and install LAMP stack instead of separate programs. Any ideas. Thanks

Comment: Check if `libapache2-mod-php` is installed on your machine.

Comment: I'm in /etc/php/7.2/mods-available and there is 10 .ini files onlycd ..

Comment: If I go /etc/php/7.2/apache2 I get conf.d directory and php,ini file